# Pagination In laravel Data table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am newbie to Laravel, I need to implement Pagination on query.
Below is the query I am sending, what next to achieve it.

```
$arrAirlines = DB::table("(SELECT air.airline_id, air.title FROM `tbl_com_airlines_airports` as aa
                        left join tbl_com_airlines as air ON air.airline_id = aa.airline_id
                        where aa.country_id ='".$countryId."' and aa.is_deleted ='0' and air.org_id ='".$orgId."'
                        and (Select count(*) from tbl_com_airlines_airports  where aa.is_domestic ='1')>1)")
                       ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The query can be written as

```
DB::table('tbl_com_airlines_airports as aa')
            ->leftjoin('tbl_com_airlines as air','air.airline_id','=','aa.airline_id')
            ->select('air.airline_id','air.title','aa.*')
            ->where('aa.country_id','=',$countryId)
            ->where('aa.is_deleted','=',0)
            ->where('aa.is_domestic','=',1)
            ->where('air.org_id','=',$orgId)
            ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You better check official laravel's documentation: [Laravel  Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination)
Try it out, if you get any other problems - better clarify it for getting relevant answer :)